# Big-O & Big-Theta: is a for loop O(1) time complexity?

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I have trouble understanding what Big-O and Big-Theta means exactly. Can someone please explain what it means illustratively?

Given that n is a constant, is the for loop of O(1) time complexity for the worst case?

Furthermore, is the worst case running time of the algorithm below O(n^2) since insertionSort is of O(n^2) complexity? If not, what is the time complexity of the below algorithm for the worst case?

```
void fnA(int[] array)
{
   ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);

   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      a2.add(array[i]);
      insertionSort(a2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of Big-O as upper bound.
If you have a for loop. Say

```
for i:= 1 to 10 print("hello");
```

then it's complexity is O(1). O(1) does not mean it completes in 1 instructions. It simply means that it does not vary in term of running time with respected to size of input (which is n). Similarly, O(n) means its running time is directly proportional with the input size.

For your example, you can make it simple by thinking like this: You have a outside for loop with complexity of O(n). Then inside the loop body, you call add (which is O(1)), and insertionSort, which is O(n^2). Then the total complexity is O(n) * (max(O(1), O(n^2)) = O(n^3).

Actually it is just the quick way of estimating the complexity. For more accurate method, you should do some math, like when the length of a2 is 1, 2, 3. ..., n, how many instructions that need to be executed in insertion sort. Then sum them up. It will give you some formula with the most significant term is n^3.

Comment: So is the for loop in the function O(1) or O(n)? Because O(n) * O(n^2) = O(n^3)?

Comment: What would be the running time in terms of Big-Theta then?

Comment: @CarolineRudolph: For loop is O(n) because it takes n as argument, so it's runtime is proportional with n.
In this case. Big-Thea is also O(n^3).

Comment: Thanks! So O(n) is the upper limit of Theta(n)?

Comment: Big-Theta is the tight-bound, means that it give you the exact estimation of running time of your program. Big-O is the upper bound, which give you the upper limit. The reason people often use Big-O, in my opinion, is sometime it is hard to get the exact Big-Theta, so you just get the upper bound, to get some idea in worst case. For one program, Big-O is equal or larger than Big-Theta.

Comment: Another thing to take not is: Big-Theta is somewhat fixed, but Big-O may not. For your above algorithm, I can say it's O(n^4). It's still correct as n^4 is somewhat the upper limit of your program. But it should never less than O(n^3).